# WebAPI and Forms Authentication CookieContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I successfully login to an **MVC 4 Web API** site and get a .**ASPXAUTH** Set-Cookie this way:

```
    private void Login()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://QQQQ/MobileAPI");
        client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var request = new RestRequest {Resource = "/api/account/Logon", Method = Method.POST};
        request.AddObject(new {Username = "john", Password = "secret"});

        var responseLogin = client.Execute(request);
        if (responseLogin.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            ProcessData(client.CookieContainer);
    }
```

As you can see I pass the **CookieContainer** to the `ProcessData()` function to then process a **RESTful** command that sits behind an `[AUTHORIZE]` Controller.

The ProcessData() call fails with an HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

**Question: I assume I am not sending the authentication correctly?**

```
    private void ProcessData(CookieContainer cookieJar)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("QQQQQ/MobileAPI");
        client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        var request = new RestRequest {Resource = "/api/values/5", Method = Method.GET};

        var responseForUser = client.ExecuteAsGet<AppUser>(request, "GET");

        if (responseForUser.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            AppUser app = responseForUser.Data;
            Console.WriteLine(app.CUSAName);
        }

        if (responseForUser.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your 2nd call send the cookie or not?

Comment: API Controller works differently then Http Controller, I doubt Authorize attribute works with API Controller. You will have to check lifecycle of API controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to reset the server with **IISRESET**. It was in a bad state perhaps.

Once I did that, the above code worked **perfectly** on an Android device.